# Is there a way to hotpatch a kernel in Debian

Tags: debian, kernel, patch

Is there any equivalent in Debian for hotpatching kernels, similar to `kpatch` in Red Hat Linux?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/buster/kpatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [KernelCare](https://www.kernelcare.com/supported-distributions-and-kernels/), [Ksplice](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/admin/ksplice).

You can try [this tutorial](https://blog.kernelcare.com/live-patching-debian-10-linux-kernel-with-kpatch) if you want to use *kpatch*.

I don't use Debian for some time.

See [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kpatch) about the *kpatch* feature.